# Python (xlrd): How to get values of multiple specific columns from an Excel?

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

Currently I am using this to read the entire row:

```
wr_stats.writerow(workbook.sheet_by_name('count').row_values(rownum))
```

Now I want to get only the values of multiple specific columns, preferably in the order of my choice. I tried:

```
wr_stats.writerow(workbook.sheet_by_name('count').row_slice(rownum, start_colx=0, end_colx=2))
```

but that prints the data type along with the values. Instead of "3", I get "number:3".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append `.value` to the cell you are reading, but I am not sure if this works with a slice.

http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.sheet.Cell

By the way, if you are using Excel 2010+ you should look into https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

From there you can use a list comprehension:

```
wr_stats.writerow([x.value for x in workbook.sheet_by_name('count').row_slice(rownum, start_colx=0, end_colx=2)])
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not and the documentation is very lacking in that regard.

Comment: Could you try to iterate over your .row_slice() and read `.value` for each element?

Comment: It works, but turns one line of code into 10 or 20, because I have to format the output as valid CSV. It's very unelegant to the point I wouldn't really consider it a solution.

I mean, it would probably be easier to use regular expressions on the output I get from row_values... which is just sad. :/

Comment: I guess you can find a pretty nice solution using a list comprehension like `wr_stats.writerow([x.value for x in workbook.sheet_by_name('count').row_slice(rownum, start_colx=0, end_colx=2)])`

Comment: Yes, that works great. Thank you. I wasn't familiar with list comprehension.